# Audio recorder unable to play after recording

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have created audio player. The recorder has startRecording button & stopRecording buttons with PlayRecording and Stop buttons as well. I notice that after recording, the recorded file will not play when clicked but the Toast will display signifying that an action is performed. I cannot detect any error in the logcat. Thanks in anticipation for a help.

my program code is below:

```
        //Requesting Run-time permission
        if (!checkPermissionFromDevice())
            requestPermission();

        //Init View
        btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStartRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startRecord);
        btnStopRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopRecord);
        
        //implementing the actions
            btnStartRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (checkPermissionFromDevice())
                    {


                    pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                            + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.amr";
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);

                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else {
                        requestPermission();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnStopRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Stop Record...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(false);

                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathSave);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);

                    if (mediaPlayer != null){
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        setupMediaRecorder();
                        Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Stop Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });




    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

        }, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    //Press Ctr+O


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice() {
        int write_external_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int record_audio_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        return write_external_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

}
```

[error encountered when i replaced the with the answer you gave me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8B6a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After close monitoring and findings, I got the solution.
Just setting btnStopRecorder **enabled** solve the issue.

Now, for anyone who may like this code
Just replace the **btnStartRecorder** button with this code below.
I am very happy now!

```
btnStartRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override*emphasized text*
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkPermissionFromDevice())
                {


                    pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                            + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.amr";
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(true);

                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your question you can check it out.

```
public class RecordAudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlayLastRecordAudio,
        buttonStopPlayingRecording, setAudioasMusic ;
File AudioSavePathInDevice;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
String audioUri;
public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("musicUri", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_audio);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonStopPlayingRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    setAudioasMusic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

    buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStop.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
    setAudioasMusic.setEnabled(false);
    setAudioasMusic.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(checkPermission()) {


                 AudioSavePathInDevice =
                        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                                + "/AudioRecording.3gp");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
                    audioUri = String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(AudioSavePathInDevice));
                } else {
                    audioUri = String.valueOf(Uri.parse(AudioSavePathInDevice.getPath())); // My work-around for new SDKs, doesn't work in Android 10.
                }
                MediaRecorderReady();

                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStart.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStop.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));

                Toast.makeText(RecordAudioActivity.this, "Recording started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }

        }
    });

    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStop.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStart.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));
            setAudioasMusic.setEnabled(true);
            setAudioasMusic.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));

            Toast.makeText(RecordAudioActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStop.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(AudioSavePathInDevice));
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(RecordAudioActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStop.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStart.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_black_alpha_50));
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));
            setAudioasMusic.setEnabled(true);
            setAudioasMusic.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ef_white));

            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                MediaRecorderReady();
            }
        }
    });

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
            if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecordAudioActivity.this, "Permission Granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RecordAudioActivity.this,"Permission " +
                            "Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
public boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            RECORD_AUDIO);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RecordAudioActivity.this, new
            String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void MediaRecorderReady(){
    mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
}
```

}

Not forget to add in your manifest if you are using android 10 or greater

```
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: I fixed your code with mine but i cannot play recorded file saved in the internal memory. My code records audio but fail to play it. That is my only challenge.

Comment: but its running in my application

Comment: i can provide you the demo also

Comment: You tried sir. Thank you! I just found out something i didn't add.

Comment: Can you help me with any loop to keep recording until i press stopRecording. If i perform onBackPressed() so as to return to second Activity, the recorder stops automatically. I want it to continue until i return to the RecorderActivity and press stop myself

Comment: You should the recording in the service when you start the recording then you start the recording in the service and when you close the activity then it will never stop your recording then you have to stop the recording and stop the service when you want and where you wants

Comment: How do i achieve this

Comment: Call the service and the start the recording in the service and when ever you want to stop you can stop it from anywhere

Comment: Give me an example guide on this new topic let me accept it as answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63790700/how-to-keep-audio-recorder-running-if-i-click-back-arrow-to-dismiss-popupmenuwin

Comment: please sir give me some assistance on this topic = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168550/how-to-create-custom-text-and-select-some-images-from-drawable-and-send-as-gift thanks