# How to keep audio recorder running if I Click back arrow to dismiss PopUpMenuWindow

Tags: android

Can you help me with any loop to keep recording until I press stopRecording. If I perform onBackPressed() so as to return to second Activity, the recorder stops automatically. I want it to continue until I return to the RecorderActivity and press stop myself.

I implemented the audio recorded in the PopupMenuWindow and when I click startRecording and I press back arrow I used this function `onBackPressed()` by calling the `finish();` the audio recorder stops recording.

**This is the code I used:**

```
//Init View
        btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStartRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startRecord);
        btnStopRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopRecord);
        //implementing the actions
        btnStartRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkPermissionFromDevice())
                {


                    pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                            + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.amr";
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(true);

                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });

        btnStopRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Stop Record...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This is my RecorderActivity.java from where I called the MyService.java

```
public class RecorderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btnStartRecorder, btnStopRecorder, btnPlay, btnStop;
    String pathSave = "";
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recorder);


        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int hight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8), (int)(hight*.5));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = -20;

        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        // Dismiss popUpMenu Window
        ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_arrow_record);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });



        //Requesting Run-time permission
        if (!checkPermissionFromDevice())
            requestPermission();

        //Init View
        btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStartRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startRecord);
        btnStopRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopRecord);
        //implementing the actions
        btnStartRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkPermissionFromDevice())
                {


                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                    i.setAction("C.ACTION_START_SERVICE");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        startForegroundService(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startService(i);

                    }

                   

                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });

        btnStopRecorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MyService.mediaRecorder.stop();
                pathSave = MyService.pathSave;
                stopService(new Intent(RecorderActivity.this, MyService.class));
                btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Stop Record...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                btnStop.setEnabled(true);
                btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(false);

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathSave);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                btnStopRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                btnStartRecorder.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);

                if (mediaPlayer != null){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Stop Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });




    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

        }, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    //Press Ctr+O


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice() {
        int write_external_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int record_audio_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        return write_external_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

}
```

**MyService.java Code implementation**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;


import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MyService extends Service {
    static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 543;
    static String pathSave = "";

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());

        pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_audio_record.amr";
            setupMediaRecorder(); // add this line in your service 
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);


        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)

                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
//add this function in your service
private void setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
    }

}
```

**I got NPE after following your instructions**

```
--------- beginning of crash
2020-09-12 12:25:02.371 24116-24116/com.igbogree.ogneneE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.igbogree.ognene, PID: 24116
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.igbogree.ognene.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare()' on a null object reference
        at com.igbogree.ognene.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:50)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3381)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1712) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the service in the manifest and you have to call the service as below in the start button

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherService.class);
        i.setAction("C.ACTION_START_SERVICE");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(i);
        }
        else
        {
            startService(i);

        }
```

Then you have to declare the audio recorder in the service and start the recording just like below

```
public class AnotherService extends Service {
static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 543;
static String pathSave = "";
public AnotherService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
        
    pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                        + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.amr";
                setupMediaRecorder();
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    

   
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground() {

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
    String channelName = "Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);


    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)

            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If you have done the service then you have to change the stop button code with this in your activity where you want to stop

```
AnotherService.mediaRecorder.stop();
pathSave = AnotherService.pathSave;
stopService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, AnotherService.class));
```

Best Regards

Comment: I have updated the OP on how I carried out your instruction. And when i tested i got Nul pointerException. Please correct me.

Comment: put you setupMediaRecorder(); function from your activity to the service and you can commit the line to check

Comment: I have posted the full code on the OP. please check and correct me in your answer. So that i will then take my time to learn how you did it. Thanks for being here for me

Comment: I can leave the commit which can help you in finding the changing

Comment: Rafaqat, You are learned!! You deserve a full chilled bottle of beer. Thank you so much! I owe you a lot. God bless you immensely. I will try my best to implement this service on my MediaPlayer which has multiple 13 play buttons and 1 stop button.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. Knowledge increases when share with others thanks again and happy to see that your application works

Comment: @Rafaqat, please help me again on this topic. Rescue me please. i have messed up my code while learning   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868666/how-to-implement-mediaplayer-service-for-multiple-play-button-sounds

Comment: If you want to play the audio in the raw folder then you don't need to work with the service you can be done this while using only activity

Comment: Okay i have changed the topic Please correct me. the mediaplayer refused to be stopped when  more than one play button is pressed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868666/how-to-implement-mediaplayer-service-for-multiple-play-button-sounds