# How to Create Multiple MediaPlayer Buttons with one stop button

Tags: android, service

I created a MediaPlayer with 21 play buttons and a stop button to control all. I also set loop to continous playback. When a user press a play button and later another play button. The mediaplayer refuse to stop.
Please rescue me. Thanks! again in anticipation for your help

**The below is what I have done that didn't work**

This is the PopUpMenuWindow.class

```
public class PopUpMenuWindowActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton StopButton;

    private static MediaPlayer mp;
    private Intent mediaServiceIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_menu_window);

        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int hight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.9), (int)(hight*.8));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = -20;

        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        // Dismiss popUpMenu Window
        ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        //Get button views IDs
        //Get button views IDs
        StopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        findViewById(R.id.play_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_5).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.play_1a).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_2a).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_3a).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_4a).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_5a).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.play_1b).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_2b).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_3b).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_4b).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_5b).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_6b).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.play_1c).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_2c).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_3c).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_4c).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_5c).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_6c).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.play_1d).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_2d).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_3d).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.play_4d).setOnClickListener(this);


        mediaServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaplayerService.class);


    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){

            // First row MediaPlayer buttons
            case R.id.play_1:
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaplayerService.class));
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_2:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track2);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_3:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track3);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_4:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track4);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_5:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track5);
                finish();
                break;

            // Second row MediaPlayer buttons
            case R.id.play_1a:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track6);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_2a:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track7);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_3a:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track8);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_4a:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bell2);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_5a:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track9);
                finish();
                break;

            // Third row MediaPlayer buttons
            case R.id.play_1b:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track10);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_2b:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track11);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_3b:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track12);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_4b:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track13);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_5b:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track14);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_6b:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track15);
                finish();
                break;



            // Fourth row MediaPlayer buttons
            case R.id.play_1c:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track16);
                finish();finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_2c:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track17);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_3c:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track18);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_4c:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track19);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_5c:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track20);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_6c:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track21);
                finish();
                break;


            // Fifth row MediaPlayer buttons
            case R.id.play_1d:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track22);
       
                finish();
                break;

                case R.id.play_2d:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track23);
                   
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_3d:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track24);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.play_4d:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track25);
                finish();
                break;


            default:
                return;
        }

        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
}

public void stop(View v) {
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaplayerService.class));

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onClick on each button you have to check each of the player just like that it will pause the other player and play the audio of the clicked button

```
if (player09==null){
        player09=MediaPlayer.create (this,R.raw.twentytwo);
        player09.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener () {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player09.pause ();
            }
        });
    }
    if(player02 != null)
        player02.pause();
    if(player03 != null)
        player03.pause();
    if(player04 != null)
        player04.pause();
    if(player05 != null)
        player05.pause();
    if(player06 != null)
        player06.pause();
    if(player07 != null)
        player07.pause();
    if(player08 != null)
        player08.pause();
    if(player01 != null)
        player01.pause();
    player09.start ();
    player09.setLooping (true);
```

and then onStop button you have to check like that

```
if(this.player01!=null){
        player01.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"8kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player02!=null){
        player02.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"10kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player03!=null){
        player03.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"12kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player04!=null){
        player04.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"14kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player05!=null){
        player05.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"16kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player06!=null){
        player06.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"17kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player07!=null){
        player07.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"20kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player08!=null) {
        player08.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"21kHz Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    if (this.player09!=null){
        player09.pause ();
        //Toast.makeText (this,"24kHz Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
```

you can stop the player or pause that may help you with single button click to stop the audio

Comment: @Rafaqat, You are a born genius!  It works perfectly!  One very good thing about you is that you understands another persons problem as though we are together. May Almighty God bless you in various ways. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I upvoted but it say i should have 15 reputations before it could be made public. Thanks Sir. I'm greatful

Comment: @Rafaqat, please help me on this topic: I ffound it very difficult to code favorites using sharedpreference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906602/how-to-implement-sharedpreference-on-recyclerview-so-as-to-save-lists-of-favorit

Answer (score 0):

You can take one array of mediaPlayer, add player once you created into array and then manage that array by index, and on stop button using loop one by one stop players.

```
ArrayList<Mediaplayer> playerarray=new ArrayList();


//Create player.....

for(int i=0;i<15;i++){

mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track_i);

playerarray.add(mp)

}


// stop player


for(int i=0;i<15;i++){

if(playerarray[i]!=null){
    playerarray[i].pause;
    playerarray[i].stop;
   }

 }
}
```