# How to Implement SharedPreference on Recyclerview so as to save lists of favorites for easy use

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

A built a lists of songs and when an item is clicked in this list takes you to NewActivity1 where full lyrics of songs is shown. I stored data in the String.xml. So, pass this data from string through adapter and show it in the NewActivity1. I used Recyclerview for this purpose. I am finding very difficult to implement this in sharedpreference.
I want the user to be able to add a song to sharedpreference from NewActivity1. Because that is where the user have read the full lyrics of song.

Please I need your help. I actually don't know how to start. If it were for the fav_icon to be placed in the row.xml I may manage to configure it.

**This is activity_tips1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/star_wars"
    tools:context=".Tips_1">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"

        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is Recyclerview **activity_favorite**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/star_wars"
    tools:context=".Tips_1">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/favorite_recyclerview">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is NewActiviy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".NewActivity1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Play song here\n\t\t\there\t\t➝"
                android:textColor="#8c0b0b" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:onClick="play"
            android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:onClick="pause"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img1"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="#565858"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
            android:indeterminate="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewera"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="#01645A" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewera"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="18dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="Full lyrics details"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="21sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="How are you"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_o"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       />



</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the data I stored in the **String.xml** from where I populate

```
<string-array name="array_titles">

        <item>"<![CDATA[001 | Ubangiji Allah, Ga Mu Nan Gabanka ]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[002 | Ubanginmu, Mai Ceto ]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[003 | Abu Duk A Duniya Ubanmu Ne Ya Yi ]]>"</item>
        etc....
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="array_lyrics">

        <item>"<![CDATA[Littafin Wakoki]]>"</item>, <item>"<![CDATA[Littafin Wakoki]]>"</item>, <item>"<![CDATA[Littafin Wakoki]]>"</item>,
       etc....
        
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="newbrandDesc">


        <item>"<![CDATA[ <p>1) Ubangiji Allah, ga mu nan gabanka.<br />Tun da farin hasken safe, mu ke nemanka.<br />Muna yabon sunanka, ya Mai Iko Duka,<br />Muna sujada, ya Mai Tsarki.</p>
<p>2) Ubangiji Uba, kai ne farkon kome,<br />Kai ka ba da Ɗanka Yesu domin cetonmu.<br />Mu da muka tayar, kai ka ji tausayinmu.<br />Muna sujada, ya Mai Tsarki.</p>
<p>3) Ubangiji Yesu, kai ne Almasihu,<br />Kai ka fanshi bayin Shaiɗan daga bautarsa.<br />Kai ka ba da jininka domin mu mutane.<br />Muna sujada, ya Mai Tsarki.</p>
<p>4) Ubangiji Ruhu, sunanka Mai Tsarki,<br />Kai ne kana koya mana hanyar cetonmu.<br />Kai ne jagabanmu, kullum sai mu bi ka.<br />Muna sujada, ya Mai Tsarki.</p>
<p>5) Allah Ubangijinmu, ɗaya cikin uku,<br />Harshe ba ya iya faɗin girman sunanka.<br />Uba, Ɗa, da Ruhu, uku cikin ɗaya,<br />Muna sujada, ya Mai Tsarki.</p> ]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[ <p>1) Ubanginmu, Mai Ceto,<br />Don zumunta ne muka zo.<br />A duniyan nan sai sakewa,<br />Wurinka fa sai hutawa.</p>
<p>2) Tun jiya, yau, har abada,<br />Madauwami ne sunanka!<br />Kai ne ka kafa duniyan nan,<br />Kai ne mai shirya gida can.</p>
<p>3) Almasihu, Cetonmu,<br />Ba mu da wani taimako,<br />Amma ƙaunarka cikakkiya,<br />Ita ce garkuwar ƴaƴanka.</p>
<p>4) Ƙaunarka ! har wa yau ta tsaya<br />Da, ka ɗanɗana mutuwa.<br />Can bisa kursiyin Allahnmu,<br />Yanzu ka rayu dominmu.</p>
<p>5) Yabo, daraja, godiya<br />Gare ka Yesu Ɗan Allah!<br />Ka cika mu da Ruhunka,<br />Ya koya mana nufinka.</p> ]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[ <p>1) Abu duk a duniya Ubanmu ne ya yi,<br />Sai mu yi ta yabonsa, Allah Mahalicci.<br />Shi ya kan ba mu ruwa a loton shukawa,<br />Har amfanin gonaki ba za mu rasa ba.</p>
<p>2) Abu duk a duniya Ubanmu ne ya yi,<br />Sai mu yi ta yabonsa, Allah Mahalicci.<br />Ya ba mu hasken rana, mu kama aikinmu.<br />Duhun dare kyautarsa, mu riƙa hutawa.</p>
<p>3) Abu duk a duniya Ubanmu ne ya yi,<br />Sai mu yi ta yabonsa, Allah Mahalicci.<br />Duk masu rai na duniya, ya kan ciyad da su.<br />Kifaye da tsuntsaye, ya san bukatarsu.</p>
<p>4) Abu duk a duniya Ubanmu ne ya yi,<br />Sai mu yi ta yabonsa, Allah Mahalicci<br />Mu kuma Masu Binsa aikin hannunsa ne, Ubanmu mai ƙauna mahaliccinmu ne.</p> ]]>"</item>
        etc....
    </string-array>
```

This is the **Tips_1.java**

```
public class Tips_1 extends Main2Activity {
    private String TAG = "Tips_2 ----- ; ";


    // Store instance variables
    private int page;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    MyAdapter1 myAdapter;
    int[] MusicFile;
    List<String> title, newDesc, description;
    int[] icon;
    ArrayList<Model1> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model1>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips1);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Hausa Audio Hymnal");

        final MoPubAdsHandlerBannerNdInterstitial adsHandler = new MoPubAdsHandlerBannerNdInterstitial(this, AddCheck.MySourceActivity);
        adsHandler.handleBannerAds();
        adsHandler.handleInterstitialAds();

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Tips_1.this, Tips_2.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(Tips_1.this, "English Audio Hymns Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        //Listview icons for song titles in position
        icon = new int[]{R.drawable.hymn, R.drawable.hymn, R.drawable.hymn};


        mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        title = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_titles));

        //listview descriptions for songs in position
        description = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_lyrics));

        //listview NewDescriptions (NewActivity1) for songs in position
        newDesc = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newbrandDesc));

        //listview soundfile file for songs in position
        MusicFile = new int[]{R.raw.aud_1, R.raw.aud_2, R.raw.aud_3};


        for (int i = 0; i < title.size(); i++) {
            Model1 model = new Model1(title.get(i), description.get(i), newDesc.get(i), icon[i], MusicFile[i]);
            //bind all strings in an array
            arrayList.add(model);
        }

        //pass result to listview class
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter1(this, arrayList);

        //bind the adapter to the listview class
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    }

}
```

**This is the MyAdapter1 class**

```
public class MyAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder1> implements Filterable {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Model1> models, filterList;  // this array list create a list of array which parameter define in our class
    CustomFilter1 filter;


    public MyAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<Model1> models) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.models = models;
        this.filterList = models;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder1 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row1, null); //this line inflate our row1


        return new MyHolder1(view); //this will return our view to holder class
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder1 myHolder, int i) {

        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); //here is position
        myHolder.mDesc.setText(models.get(i).getDesc());
        myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getIcon()); // here we used imge resource

        myHolder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemClickListener1() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

                String gTitle = models.get(position).getTitle();
                String gDesc = models.get(position).getDesc();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mImageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                //get our data with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity1.class);
                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", models.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", models.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
                intent.putExtra("soundfile", models.get(position).getSoundfile());
                intent.putExtra("iImage", bytes);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        });

   }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (filter == null){
            filter = new CustomFilter1(filterList, this);
        }

        return filter;
    }
}
```

**This is what I was trying to do that got me confused in the whole process**

```
public class PreferenceUtils {
    private static final PreferenceUtils ourInstance = new PreferenceUtils();
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static Context context;

    private static String APP_DATA_NAME = "SONGS";

    static PreferenceUtils getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private PreferenceUtils() {
    }

    public static void initialize(Context c) {
        sharedPreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(APP_DATA_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        context = c;
    }

    public static String getPreference(String key, String defaultValue) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) return null;
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static boolean getPreference(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) return false;
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static Set<String> getPreference(String key) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) return null;
        return sharedPreferences.getStringSet(key,null);
    }

    public static void setPreference(String key, String value) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) return;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void setPreference(String key, boolean value) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) return;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void setPreference(String key, Set<String> value) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) return;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

**This is my row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/song"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#740303"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainDesc"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#262626"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favorite"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_o"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This also what I have been able to do in model.class**

```
public class Model {

    String title;
    String desc;

    //favorites songs key
    private static String FAVORITE_SONGS_KEY = "favorites";

    //song identifier
    int id;

    int icon;

    //constructor
    public Model(String title, String desc, int icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    //getters


    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

    public void setFavorite() {
        if (isFavorite()) unset();
        else addTofavorite();
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        String listIds = PreferenceUtils.getPreference(FAVORITE_SONGS_KEY, null);
        if (listIds == null) return false;
        List ids = new Gson().fromJson(listIds, List.class);
        if (ids == null) ids = new ArrayList();
        return ids.contains(String.valueOf(this.id));
    }

    private void unset() {
        String listIds = PreferenceUtils.getPreference(FAVORITE_SONGS_KEY, null);
        if (listIds == null) listIds = new String();
        List ids = new Gson().fromJson(listIds, List.class);
        if (ids == null) ids = new ArrayList();
        ids.add(String.valueOf(this.id));
        if (ids.contains(String.valueOf(this.id))) ids.remove(String.valueOf(this.id));
        PreferenceUtils.setPreference(FAVORITE_SONGS_KEY, new Gson().toJson(ids));
    }

    private void addTofavorite() {
        String listIds = PreferenceUtils.getPreference(FAVORITE_SONGS_KEY, null);
        if (listIds == null) listIds = new String();

        List ids = new Gson().fromJson(listIds, List.class);
        if (ids == null) ids = new ArrayList();
        ids.add(String.valueOf(this.id));
        PreferenceUtils.setPreference(FAVORITE_SONGS_KEY, new Gson().toJson(ids));
    }
}
```

[image: This is where I want the Icon to be]

Comment: Yes you can place the fav icon in the row and then on fav click put the all the detail of the song into the share preferences and then use where you want on click you have to change the icon color, place it to the share preferences and on another click remove from it and change the icon color

Comment: what do you wants on fav btn click

Comment: this all is happening in adapter

Answer (score -1):

you have to create the arraylist in the adapter just like that the data type of the array is define as you want e.g  `public ArrayList<String> selectedImages;`
then onbindView and then on fav icon click listener like that

```
myViewHolder.favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            if (selectedImages.contains(images.get(i))) {
                myViewHolder.mylinear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                selectedImages.remove(images.get(i));
            } else {
                myViewHolder.favBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                selectedImages.add(images.get(i)); //this is the list which you passing to the adapter
                Log.e("selected",selectedImages.toString());
            }
            return true;
    });
```

then you make getter function for this array list which you created in the adapter like that

```
public ArrayList<String> getSelectedImages() {
    Log.e("selected",selectedImages.toString());
    return selectedImages;
}
```

now you can use call this method where you wants like that
create the object of the adapter like that

```
ImageAdapter applicationimagesadapter;
```

then create the array list to save the result from the adapter getter function

```
 ArrayList<String> images;
```

then call the getter function with the adapter object

```
if (applicationimagesadapter != null) {
        images = applicationimagesadapter.getSelectedImages();
    }
```

and thats it